# Combining PHP array by index

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following two arrays. I need a way in PHP to combine them together so that the values at index[i] from both arrays are added to the same index in the final array.

Array 1

```
[0] => '123456'
[1] => '654123'
[2] => '987456'
[3] => '489522'
[4] => '014779'
```

Array 2

```
[0] => 'feature'
[1] => 'promo'
[2] => 'other'
[3] => 'start'
[4] => 'end'
```

Final Array I need

```
[0] => ['123456', 'feature']
[1] => ['654123', 'promo']
[2] => ['987456', 'other']
[3] => ['489522', 'start']
[4] => ['014779', 'end']
```

Answer (score 10):

By far the easiest way is to use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$result = array_map(null, $array1, $array2));
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/69YYeO)**.

Comment: And the most elegant... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($array1 as $index => $value1) {
    $finalArray[$index] = array($value1, $array2[$index]);
}
```

Comment: First answer? Mine was earlier and more detailed!

Comment: @PDev: Your answer has three code snippets, only the second of which works as intended. The other two just detract from its value.

Answer (score 0):

As both have a numeric key, you can do it with foreach:

```
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    $finalArray[$value] = $array1[$key];
}
```

It's a simple solution, but it should work. It just gets each value of the second array and puts it into the final array.

Or, if you need a number in the final array also:

```
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) {
    $finalArray[$key] = array($value, $array1[$key]);
}
```

Or, the easiest way is to just use the array_merge function:

```
$finalArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet :)

```
 $array_combined = array();
 foreach($array1 as $key=>$value)
 {
    $array_combined[$key] = array($array1[$key], $array2[$key]); 
 }
```